# Conformal metric for hemispheres in 3d hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm reading through T. Needham's "Visual Differential Geometry and Forms" and am a bit stumped by exercise 27 (chapter 7).

The exercise is about the metric of hemispheres in 3D hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^3$ and illustrates that these hemispheres (which end on the horizon) are hyperbolic planes $\mathbb{H}^2$.

The first few parts of the problem pose no issue.  We start from the metric of the hemisphere in polar coordinates ($\theta,\phi$) and with coordinate transformations $u=\tan\theta$ and $u=1/\sinh \xi$ a conformal metric is obtained

$$ds^2 = \frac{d\phi^2 + d\xi^2}{\sinh^2 \xi}.$$

The last step is where I'm stuck.  It asks to find a conformal mapping $(\phi,\xi \to x,y)$ such that the standard $\mathbb{H}^2$ metric  $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$ is recovered.  It has a hint

> Set $dy/y = d\xi /\sinh \xi$,

but that does not seem to help me.  I can solve that equation to $y(\xi)$, but it seems to me that having a map $y(\xi)$ then implies having $x(\phi)$ in order to keep a conformal metric, which then cannot obey the Cauchy-Riemann equations for this conformal map.

Am I misreading the hint or just on the wrong track?  Any general hints to how to approach the problem?

Comment: Correspondingly let $$\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{d\phi}{\sinh\xi}$$ and you're done.

Comment: That was also my first thought, but how would this give something consistent?  Due to the $\xi$ dependence in the equation you would have $x(\xi,\phi)$ and $$dx = (\partial_\xi x) d\xi + (\partial_\phi x) d\phi$$ which doesn't agree with the above equation (and would also spoil the conformal nature of the metric).

Comment: @kuzine I am having the same question here. Have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: @sean-ian No I'm afraid.  Haven't looked back at it since.